# Is it possible to efficiently extract phonons from a lattice?

Tags: thermodynamics, temperature, laser, phonons

The population inversion generated in lasers occurs in multi-level atomic systems.  As an example, the Nd:YAG energy diagram is shown below.  The pump pushes the Nd ions up to the upper levels, and they rapidly relax down to the $^4F_{3/2}$ level via a radiationless transition.  This radiationless transition gives off a phonon to the lattice with a well defined energy.

The typical way of extracting the energy given off during this process is to wait until the phonon relaxes into a background temperature and extract the heat with a heat bath.  The ability to extract this heat quickly enough limits the performance of some lasers.

$\hspace{150px}$[image: Nd:YAG Energy Diagram]

**My question is:** Given that the phonons in the lattice initially have a well defined energy, is it possible to use a resonant extraction technique to remove them from the lattice more efficiently?